# Метод обрывается после вызова Random.Range на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;

public class CreaturesMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float creatureSpeed;
    float currentVerticalSpeed;
    float currentHorizontalSpeed;
    int wallNum;

    private void Start()
    {
        TimerCallback tm = new TimerCallback(Buffer);
        Timer timer = new Timer(tm, 0, 0, 2000);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Translate(currentHorizontalSpeed, currentVerticalSpeed, 0);
    }

    void Buffer(object obj)
    {
        wallNum = Random.Range(1, 5); // прекращает работу
        switch(wallNum)
        {
            case 1:
                Debug.Log("1");
                currentVerticalSpeed = creatureSpeed;
                currentHorizontalSpeed = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                Debug.Log("2");
                currentHorizontalSpeed = -creatureSpeed;
                currentVerticalSpeed = 0;
                break;
            case 3:
                Debug.Log("3");
                currentVerticalSpeed = -creatureSpeed;
                currentHorizontalSpeed = 0;
                break;
            case 4:
                Debug.Log("4");
                currentHorizontalSpeed = creatureSpeed;
                currentVerticalSpeed = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить перед `Random.Range` вот это `UnityEngine.`

Comment: К сожалению не помогает...

Comment: А вы через отладчик проверяли? Прям берет и без причины выходит из функции?

Comment: Именно. Сейчас, вставлю весь код, думаю, это может быть из-за Timer

Comment: А почему вы решили что этот метод вообще запускается?

Comment: И вообще эта штука наверняка не в потоке Unity будет вызываться. Сильно проще работать с одним потоком, например с помощью [корутин](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) или простой переменной прибавляющей в `Update` `Time.DeltaTime`. Для многопоточности есть более-менее стандартные [JobSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html) и [UniTask](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask)

Comment: Дебаг показал, что метод запускается. Может это конфликт Timer и Random какой-нибудь?

Comment: Добавьте в начала метода какой-нибудь `Debug.Log("HelloWorld")`. Если он выводится, то значит метод вызывается и проблема в потоках. (`Debug.Log` срабатывает из любого потока). 
(ну и я бы ещё раз сказал, что в этом кейсе игра с потоками не стоит свеч и корутины подойдут вам куда больше, чем `TimerCallback`.)

Comment: Да, Log в начале метода работает. Значит я попробую через корутины

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;

public class CreaturesMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float creatureSpeed;
    float currentVerticalSpeed;
    float currentHorizontalSpeed;
    int wallNum;

    private void Start()
    {
      // 0 - начальный старт вызова Buffer, 5 - каждый раз будет вызывать Buffer 
      InvokeRepeating("Buffer", 0, 5);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Translate(currentHorizontalSpeed, currentVerticalSpeed, 0);
    }

    void Buffer()
    {
        wallNum = Random.Range(1, 5); 
        switch(wallNum)
        {
            case 1:
                Debug.Log("1");
                currentVerticalSpeed = creatureSpeed;
                currentHorizontalSpeed = 0;
                break;
            case 2:
                Debug.Log("2");
                currentHorizontalSpeed = -creatureSpeed;
                currentVerticalSpeed = 0;
                break;
            case 3:
                Debug.Log("3");
                currentVerticalSpeed = -creatureSpeed;
                currentHorizontalSpeed = 0;
                break;
            case 4:
                Debug.Log("4");
                currentHorizontalSpeed = creatureSpeed;
                currentVerticalSpeed = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Огроменное Вам спасибо!! Всё отлично работает))